# Multiplied arrays in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i multiple content in all arrays in array?

`[[3, 2], [1, 2, 1], [7, 8]] //=>`

`[6, 2, 56]`

I don't understand how i need to use "for...of".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with the following one-liner:

```js
const arr= [[3, 2], [1, 2, 1], [7, 8]];
console.log(arr.map(ar=>ar.reduce((a,c)=>a*c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Massmann is absolutely correct, and his answer is the best one for just about any circumstance I can think of.  However, if you want to see how to use `of` I have given an example here.

```js
const arr= [[3, 2], [1, 2, 1], [7, 8]];

for(el of arr) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(el));
  console.log(el.reduce((accumulator, current)=>accumulator * current));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A hard coded version is multiplying array[0] x array[x]. Or you can use an enhanced for loop

Comment: What is `x` in this?